# How Do I populate my table in SQL with input from the user? PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Just starting out with PHP. I have code that gets user input through a form and enters the input into a mySQL table. The code has no parse errors. But when a user submits their name and email. It is not going into the table, the table is still empty, and I cannot seem to figure out the problem. Here is my code:

```
<div id="main">
<h1>Insert data into database using PDO</h1>
<div id="login">
    <h2>Students Form</h2>
    <hr/>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label>Student Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="Fname" required="required" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name"/><br/><br/>
        <label>Student Email :</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required" placeholder="Pear@gmsil.com"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br/>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<?php
//server name
$db_hostname = "lll";
//database name 
$db_database = "lll";
//username
$db_username = "lll";
$db_password = "lll;";
$db_charset = "utf8mb4";
//a string specifying the database type, the hostname and name of the   database
$dsn = "mysql:host=$db_hostname;dbname=$db_database;charset=$db_charset";
          $opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE         =>  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
          PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE =>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
          PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
      );

  try {
   //create connection
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,$db_username,$db_password,$opt);

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {   

      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
          PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO students (name,email)";
          VALUES ('". $_POST["name"] ."','" . $_POST["email"] . "');
   if ($pdo->query($sql)) {
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Student Inserted Successfully');</script>";
     } else {
         echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully  Inserted.');</script>";
        }
 }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You have an obvious syntax error. You should be getting that shown on your page or a blank page altogether.

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO students (name,email)";` < that is a valid statement in PHP and it *ends* your statement.

Comment: I'm voting this as a typo.

Comment: `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
          PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` why do you have that inside `if (isset($_POST["submit"])){...}` ? That's another typo.

Comment: and using id's, suggests JS somewhere.

Comment: I love it when they just leave or don't respond to comments; I'm out.

Comment: Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. With those you have patterns you could follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts. What you have here is a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between.

Comment: @JohnConde where is the obvious syntax error ? The page is not blank

Answer (score 0):

in the line of code where you write the SQL statement, you placed an extra `";` before the second half of the query.

Change

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO students (name,email)";
      VALUES ('". $_POST["name"] ."','" . $_POST["email"] . "');
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO students (name,email) VALUES ('". $_POST["name"] ."','" . $_POST["email"] . "');
```

This should fix the problem with your failed inserts.

Comment: Correct solution to immediate problem, or at least one of them. They should, however, use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php